# Convert matrix to raster with assigning LCC projection

Tags: r, raster

I would like to convert data-only matrix (not a xyz type of table) to raster layer. Each column and row represents longitude and latitude.

However, while rasterizing the matrix, I'm struggling with assigning CRS on it.

My data should be projected in LCC projection. And all the parameters that I know are below.

> ```
> DX: 7500.f (meter)
> DY: 7500.f (meter)
> CEN_LAT: 37.99787f
> CEN_LON: 127.4592f
> TRUELAT1: 30.f
> TRUELAT2: 60.f
> ```

So I assigned `mycrs` with `CRS()` function, and assigned it as below.
I could not assign `res=7500` argument in `raster()` because it returned an error.

```
mx <- matrix(rep(1, 13770), nrow=90, ncol=153) # reproducible example of mx
mycrs <- CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=37.99787 +lon_0=127.4592 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
r <- raster(mx, crs=mycrs)
```

> ```
> class       : RasterLayer 
> dimensions  : 90, 153, 13770  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
> resolution  : 0.006535948, 0.01111111  (x, y)
> extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=37.99787 +lon_0=127.4592 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
> data source : in memory
> names       : layer 
> values      : 1, 1  (min, max)
> ```

Well, the console did not return any warning, but the result was awkward.

The `dimensions` seems ok but `resolution` and `extent` must be wrong.

The domain of the layer should be like

```
(123.25, 43.23) ------- (131.78, 43.17)
       :                        :
       :                        :
(123.80, 32.73) ------- (131.01, 32.68)
```

Is there any other method to convert `mx` into raster with the given CRS parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the extent in terms of the coordinate reference system (crs), `llc` in this case. The data source should provide that for the data to be usable. You have the extent in lon/lat, but not in llc. We can estimate it:

```
library(raster)         
e <- extent(123.25, 131.78, 32.68, 43.23)
p <- as(e, "SpatialPolygons")
crs(p) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

library(rgdal)
llc <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=37.99787 +lon_0=127.4592 +datum=WGS84"
pp <- spTransform(p, llc)
```

And create a RasterLayer

```
r <- raster(pp)
```

Now set the resolution (from what you provide I understand that it is 7500 m)

```
res(r) <- 7500
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 152, 105, 15960  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 7500, 7500  (x, y)
#extent     : -390412.6, 397087.4, -567400.8, 572599.2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=37.99787 +lon_0=127.4592 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

This does not match the number of rows and columns that you provided (but where did you get these?).

The extent could be approximately correct, but that it is not guaranteed at all. The data provider should really give it to you to be exact. If you actually know the number of rows and columns, then it is obviously wrong.

Comment: Yes, I didn't pay attention to the extent provided. I tried to reproject but I wasn't able to get the same column and rows (nrows = 90, ncols = 153) so I deleted my response. Thanks for correcting me.